# Could I wrap c++ library to Adobe Air native extension for mobile IOS/Android

Tags: android, c++, ios, air, adobe

Can I wrap a C++ library to Adobe Air native extension IOS/Android?

I have a C++ library that was written by third party. I want to use that library for an adobe air native extension for mobile?
Will I be able to do it. If so, where can I find some guidelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer the Android part of the question.

I haven't seen it spelled out explicitly in the Adobe Air documentation that this is possible, but in the Adobe Help docs for Adobe Air, section [Packaging a native extension: Building the native library](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7fff.html#WSdb11516da818ea8d49ce0fe713341ed67cf-8000), it says:

> Android native libraries: When you use the Android NDK, provide a shared library with a filename as follows (etc)

The [NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/overview.html) as you may know lets you to implement parts of your Android app using native-code languages including C++.

I take it this reference in the docs means it's possible. As a starting point, I'd get familiar with the details of the NDK.

While this is not a detailed guideline on how to proceeed, I hope it provides a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Aside from the Adobe Air part of the question, the native library would not realistically be usable unless it was either already compiled with the NDK toolchain to the desired assortment of Android ABIs, or available in source form.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to building an ANE to wrap the C++ library is to compile it into Flash bytecode, using the new Adobe "C++ to Flash" compiler (previously known as Alchemy). It can produce a swf that you can later call from ActionScript. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/using-cplusplus-code-path-finding.html) that explains how to do it. And [here](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/) is its official website.

Answer (score 0):

for iOS you can use the c library if you can statistically link to it. ANE on iOS does not support dynamic linking (as of 3.2 not sure if something changed in newer releases). Static linking is fairly easy process in Xcode just google it.

for Android:

If you have the .so file you can write your ANE in JAVA and use jni(System.loadLibrary) to talk to your cpp library. its better than writing ANE in CPP completely. See [ane documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2482335412ffea65006-8000.html) "Including additional Android shared .so libraries in the ANE package" section to know more.